# Flutter child widget refreshing parent widget - how to not do this

Tags: flutter, dart

When the class members of child class **PartnerInviter** are changed inside the child class, somehow it changes the state of the parent class as well which is **PartnerConnect**. isInviteOption: true, isInviteSent: false => Parent widget resets the flag to false, false. I thing build of PartnerConnect is getting called. How do I fix this?

Parent widget is:

```
class PartnerConnect extends StatefulWidget{

  bool isInviter = true;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return PartnerConnectState();
  }
}

class PartnerConnectState extends State<PartnerConnect>{

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  double card_elevation = 1;
  TextEditingController phoneNumber = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: widget.isInviter ? PartnerInviter(
          isInviteOption: false,
          isInviteSent: false,
          scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey,
        ) : PartnerInvitee(
            isInvitationAccepted: true,
            inviterNumber: '9********0',
            scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Partner Connect'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Child widget is:

```
class PartnerInviter extends StatefulWidget{

  bool isInviteOption = false;
  bool isInviteSent = false;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  PartnerInviter({this.isInviteOption, this.isInviteSent, this.scaffoldKey});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _PartnerInviterState();
  }
}

class _PartnerInviterState extends State<PartnerInviter> {

  double card_elevation = 1;
  TextEditingController phoneNumber = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return inviterConnectBody();
  }

  Widget inviterConnectBody(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
            child: numberInputWidget(),
            visible: widget.isInviteOption,
            replacement: Container(
              child: Visibility(
                child: RequestReceivedWidget(phoneNum: phoneNumber.value.text),
                visible: widget.isInviteSent,
                replacement: Container(
                  child: RequestRevokeWidget(phoneNum: phoneNumber.value.text),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget RequestRevokeWidget({String phoneNum}){

    return Card(
      elevation: card_elevation,
      color: Colors.deepPurple[50],
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Partner connected'),
              subtitle: Text('Registered number: ${phoneNum}'),
            ),
            Center(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04, right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                      child: Text('Revoke access', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        widget.isInviteOption = true;
                        SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Partness access successfully revoked'),);
                        widget.scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),);
  }

  Widget RequestReceivedWidget({String phoneNum}){

    return Card(
      elevation: card_elevation,
      color: Colors.deepPurple[50],
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text('Waiting for partner to accept invite'),
          subtitle: Text('Registered number: ${phoneNum}'),
        ),
      ),)
    ;
  }

  Widget numberInputWidget(){
    final buttonMargin = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.038;

    return Card(
      elevation: card_elevation,
      color: Colors.deepPurple[50],
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Partner'),
              subtitle: Text('Enter the phone number'),
            ),
            Center(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04, right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: phoneNumber,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    enabled: true,
                    maxLength: 10,
                    maxLengthEnforced: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixText: '+91-',
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: buttonMargin, right: buttonMargin),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                elevation: 0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Text(
                  "Confirm & Proceed",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "Nunito",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'(^[0-9]*$)');
                  if (phoneNumber.text.isEmpty) {
                    widget.scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text("Please enter the mobile number")));
                  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(phoneNumber.text) || phoneNumber.text.length < 10) {
                    widget.scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text("Please enter valid mobile number")));
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.isInviteOption = false;
                      widget.isInviteSent = true;
                    });

                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),)
    ;
  }

}
```